# Python WMI querying with variable query text

Tags: python, wmi

I'm new to Python (and coding in general) and I'm working my way through the WMI module.  What I am looking for is a way to query WMI for event log errors filtered for date.

For example, if I do the following, it works:

```
events = userwmi.query("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where Type='error' AND TimeWritten='20120806000000.000000-000'")
```

If I do this:

```
q_text = "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where Type='error' AND TimeWritten='20120806000000.000000-000'"
events = userwmi.query(q_text)
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    events = user.query(q_text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in query
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 84, in next
    return _get_good_object_(self._iter_.next(), resultCLSID = self.resultCLSID)
com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)
```

The query was syntactically invalid.  I'm guessing that's because rather than passing the text as is, query() is being passed an object representing the text?  I've also tried userwmi.query(wql=q_text) to explicitly specify the keyword argument being used.

My goal is to use the datetime module to get the current date at runtime, then construct a date string one month prior (taking into account leading zeroes and year changes if necessary), then construct a WQL statement that takes the new date.  Right now I can construct the date according to the format above, combine that with the rest of a query statement and print the complete statement.  I can manually copy that statement and paste it into the query() method and run it successfully.

Is there any hope for me here?

Comment: In both cases the method is being passed a string, the _same_ string value, so I can't see how _that_ could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am going to continue trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here: string encoding.  By building the string and then encoding it as utf-8 everything works.